Creating Multiple Tables in BigQuery
I have a database that I'm trying to move over from SQL Server to BigQuery. In this database I have 286 tables and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get them all uploaded in one go. Is this possible or do I have to create one table at a time? I have scripted all 286 tables into one file but I'm thinking I may have to do each one individually if creating multiple tables at once isn't possible.
We also use a bucket where we send the files to so maybe that can be another route to get these tables created. I can upload them to our bucket and then when creating the table it asks where to create from and I can select Google Cloud Storage. What would be the best route to go for what I'm trying to achieve? Thank you in advance for helping someone newer to BigQuery out!
Edit: Something else I was thinking is I can make the tables into CSV and upload them but the issue I was having with that was the syntax. BigQuery doesn't like SQL Server Syntax and would give me a ton of errors So I'm manually having to create the schemas.
I haven't tested anything yet, getting feedback for the best route to use or suggestions.

Option 1: Using the BigQuery Console
Navigate to BigQuery Console: Go to the BigQuery Console.
Create a Dataset (if not already created):
Click + Create Dataset in the left panel.
Enter a dataset name, data location, and optional expiration date, then click Create.
Create Tables:
Within the dataset, click + Create Table.
Choose the Source:
Empty Table: Create a table from scratch.
Upload or Google Cloud Storage: Create a table based on imported data.
Define the schema for the table by adding fields (columns).
Click Create Table.
Repeat this step to create additional tables.

Thank you! I'm actually doing this method which probably means it's going to take awhile to do 286 tables. When I'm doing empty table its giving me the option to edit the schema so that's what I'm doing. The one part that would make it easier is if the text part of the schema worked because than I could just copy paste my tables but it doesn't like the SQL Server syntax so I have to use the drop downs and do it that way. I tried the GCS way but because it's SQL Server I would get so many errors. Also would this mean I would have to script each table individually to get them into the bucket?
